# Systematic way of finding the Killing vector of a specific mass

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, vector-fields

I have a specific black hole solution (in AdS space) with a particular energy given. The energy was computed in the paper by assuming the validity of the first law ($dE = T dS + \Omega dJ + \Phi dQ$) and integrating it.

This energy is different from the one I get via Komar integral or ADM, when using the Killing vector $\xi^\mu = (\partial_t)^\mu$. I would like to find the timelike Killing vector that would give me the same energy calculated in the paper (when plugged into either the Komar or ADM formalism). So given a specific black hole energy, is there a systematic way to find the Killing vector field that would be responsible for reproducing it?

Comment: Won't the specific black hole solution be determined by E, J of the solution? Moreover, integrating the first law gives the difference in energy between two infinitesimally close black hole solutions. And I don't know how you can find the exact energy. Could you give a link to the paper?

Comment: @Abhikumbale $E$ and $J$ are calculated, they are not parameters in the solution. Complicated black hole solutions are usually found by looking for a solution to the convenient equations of motion (eg. Einstein and Maxwell if you are looking for a charged BH solution.) Conserved quantities like energy and angular momentum are then found using some formalism for calculating them. I recommend you check the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408217.